# Generics C# How to pass a property of a generic object by parameter

Tags: c#, generics, predicate

I have created this method but it has a problem that I couldn't sort it out.

How can I pass by parameter the predicate? Because "x.IsActive" and "source.Id" and "x.Id" vary, normally all the objects I will pass by parameter have IsActive and Id properties.

```
 public static Differences<T> CheckChanges<T>(List<T> sourceTable, List<T> destinationTable)
    {
        var differences = new Differences<T>();

        foreach (var sourceItem in sourceTable.Where(x => x.IsActive))
        {
            var destinationItem = destinationTable.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == sourceItem.Id);
        }

        return differences;
    }
```

Comment: So how are the type parameters you plan to use related? Are they all inheriting from Account?

Comment: No, I have different tables, most of them (maybe all) I can filter using .Id and .IsActive. So I could pass the predicates by parameter or some generic way to use .Id and .IsActive for all of my generic objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make all your objects inherit from a common interface, this could be much easier:

```
public interface IAccount
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Your method signature would look more like this then:

```
public static Differences<IAccount> CheckChanges(List<IAccount> sourceTable, List<IAccount> destinationTable)
```

Comment: Ow! I just found that ALL my objects have this interface inherit:   public interface IHasId<T>
  {
    T Id { get; }
  }

Comment: However, I must pass by parameter the object List<IHasId<int>> and not anymore List<Account>   So how can I convert my List<Account> to List<IHasId<int> ?

Comment: Yes, it is working now, however I have a code that instances the class `var ob = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` but this generates now this error: **Cannot create an instance of an interface.**

Comment: For that, make sure `T` is the same type it was previously.  It should be a class that inherits from your interface, not the interface itself.

Comment: Sorry? i don't understand what you mean... My error now is this: List<Account> is not assignable to parameter type List<IHasId<int>>   when I try to call the method CheckChanges (as I am passing List<IHasId<int>>) by parameter but my object is List<Account>   (Account is inherited from IHasId<int>)   how can I fix it?

Comment: The list should be `var list = new List<IHasId<int>>();`  Then add `Account` objects to it: `list.Add(new Account());` --- or --- `list.Add(Activator.CreateInstance<Account>());`

Comment: Great, it is working everything now, this code here is beautiful! But I think it is slower than before, I have to process 1 million records...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Differences<T> CheckChanges<T>(List<T> sourceTable, 
                                             List<T> destinationTable, 
                                             Func<T, bool> predicate,
                                             Func<T, T, bool> pred2)
{
    var differences = new Differences<Account>();

    foreach (var sourceItem in sourceTable.Where(predicate))
    {
        var destinationItem = destinationTable.FirstOrDefault(x => pred2(x, sourceItem));
    }

    return differences;
}
```

Comment: Sample usage and doing something with return result (`differences`) would improve the answer... As well possibly some text...

Comment: Cool!! What's the difference between the parameters: predicate and pred2?

Comment: They are used in different places. One lets you send a condition for the `Where`, and the other is used in the `FirstOrDefault` with `sourceItem` as one of the T's

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I hardly have a few minutes here and there at the moment. Just posted to head him in the right direction. Feel free to edit.

Comment: All good, I just need to know about performance, as this code will be ran 1 million times for each record in my database, how can I get better performance? Is generics slower than other methods?

Comment: @RogerOliveira Use the `Stopwatch` class and benchmark it.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I am using Stopwatch to measure it, thanks